# Visual Basic 6.0 Passing by reference problem

Tags: vb6, pass-by-reference

In the following code, I get a compile time error:

```
ByRef Argument type mismatch.
```

But if I change the declaration of i,j to :

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
```

The error goes away. Why?

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
Dim i, j As Integer
    i = 5
    j = 7
    Call Swap(i, j)
End Sub

Public Sub Swap(ByRef X As Integer, ByRef Y As Integer)
Dim tmp As Integer
    tmp = X
    X = Y
    Y = tmp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because when you do this in VB6:

```
Dim i, j As Integer
```

It reads to the compiler as

```
Dim i As Variant, j As Integer
```

Leading to your type mismatch. The answer is, as you said, to declare both with types, either as in your code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
```

Or on a single line, a la:

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
```

Answer (score 3):

In VB 6, I is considered a variant, not an integer in the case you're describing.

Here's an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56ht941f(VS.80).aspx) that describes the behavior.